# Auding branch of NFS to find unique groups

Tags: linux, permissions, nfs

Is there a way to audit all the different groups used in a directory tree on my NFS system? I want to see all the different groups that are used in hopes of condensing the total amount of groups on my system.

Currently Ive been running into permissions issues for users related to NFS 16 group limit, where creation of a new group to deal with a specific permissions case causes users elsewhere to loose permission because they are in more than 16 groups.

https://www.xkyle.com/solving-the-nfs-16-group-limit-problem/

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing on NFS side to do that but you can script it using `stat` command.

Inside your NFS folder you can just execute this:

`$ find .  -exec stat -c "User:%U Group:%G" {} \; | uniq`

*I'm still wondering why this limitation is not fix in NFS client (from the kernel) or at least being able to set the groups to be sent to the server*

Comment: uniq only filters out adjacent lines, so maybe it is better to sort the output first.
depending on the sort implementation you are using you might get away with just sort -u like this:

find .  -exec stat -c "User:%U Group:%G" {} \; | sort -u

else you will to have an extra pipe like this:

find .  -exec stat -c "User:%U Group:%G" {} \; | sort | uniq